# Tomcat: Replace DBCP by OracleConnectionPoolDataSource

Tags: oracle, tomcat, configuration, apache-commons-dbcp

since a few days, I try to replace Tomcats dbcp by Oracle's connection pool. That's required, because a web application uses some Oracle specific features.

Currently, the JNDI datasoure is configured that way:

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/oracle"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    auth="Container"
    type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"
    factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
    user="*****"
    password="*****"        
    url="*****"
/>
```

When I take a connection from the pool, it's still of type 
org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.PoolGuardConnectionWrapper

Can someone give me a hint, what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Markus

Comment: Ok, after a few days I found the problem. The application uses Spring. Somewhere in the application context, there is a bean definition for a DataSource using Jakarta Commons DBCP. The code throwing the ClassCastException operates with a Connection that is taken from the DataSource from application context. The mix-up of JNDI and Spring was too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the wrapped connection by calling: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolingDataSource.PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.html#getDelegate()

Then cast it into the concrete Oracle connection object.

BTW: Nothing is going wrong, most (if not all) application servers wrap the contrete connection by using some kind of wrapper.

Comment: But what, if I want to replace the whole pool manager? According to the book "Professional Apache Tomcat 6" this should be possible. There is an example how to use C3P0 instead of DBCP, but this is not working, DBCP is still used. In the example, the factory-attribute is used to replace the default factory by org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory. As far as I understand this example, the new factory "will create an instance of cp30-managed data sources [...]". In that case, it would not make much sense to manage connections by DBCP, that are already manage by another pool...